# CosmosDb complex sorting

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a CosmosDb collection with documents that look like this:

```
{
  "status": [0/1]
  "someFlag": [true/false]
  "score": 24.0
}
```

I would like to query this collection with some complex sorting:

- First I would like to get documents where status is 1 and someFlag is true
- Second, status is 1 and someFlag is false
- Third, status is 0 and someFlag is true
- Fourth, status is 0 and someFlag is false

So I have 4 sections and in each one I want it to be ordered from the highest score.
Can I do that somehow with a single SQL query or with .NET client with single request to the db?

Comment: So... this really seems to be more about filtering, within a `WHERE` clause (you can have multiple filters using `OR` and `AND`). I would suggest posting your SQL query, and where you're having issues.

Comment: It's not about filtering, I want to fetch all of the records and order them like I described. The only way I can think of solving this is to make 4 queries and join results, but I'd like to know if there's a way to do this in single query.

Comment: Right - I pointed you to `or` and `and` within a `where` clause, which are designed to do what you're asking. Combine that with an `order by`. This is also in the SQL API documentation. I suggest trying to get a query working and then editing your question to show your specific output issues, errors, etc.

Comment: So I think the confusion here, is that you didn't provide an example of what your desired output should be (which is why, in my  original comment, I asked for clarification). If you're trying to create multiple sorted document lists within a single query, then no, you cannot do such a thing in a single query. I provided an answer, but it assumes you wanted four queries in a union.

Comment: @Husker I help you post the answer. This can be  beneficial to other community members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following SQL and ut required composite index with those three fields to work.

```
SELECT * 
FROM c 
WHERE c.Status = 0 OR c.Status = 1 
ORDER BY c.Status DESC, c.SomeFlag DESC, c.Score DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add some information.

If you have a collection like this

```
[{"status": 0,"someFlag": true,"score": 24},{"status": 0,"someFlag": false,"score": 23},
{"status": 1,"someFlag": false,"score": 20},{"status": 1,"someFlag": true,"score": 28},
{"status": 0,"someFlag": false,"score": 31},{"status": 0,"someFlag": true,"score": 33},
{"status": 1,"someFlag": false,"score": 17},{"status": 1,"someFlag": true,"score": 15}]
```

And you want to get a query result like this with a single sql in cosmosbd:

```
[{"status": 0,"someFlag": true,"score": 24},{"status": 0,"someFlag": true,"score": 33},
{"status": 0,"someFlag": false,"score": 23},{"status": 0,"someFlag": false,"score": 31},
{"status": 1,"someFlag": true,"score": 15},{"status": 1,"someFlag": true,"score": 28},
{"status": 1,"someFlag": false,"score": 17},{"status": 1,"someFlag": false,"score": 20}]
```

I think it's impossible. I have tried a sql like this but it failed. As you said you can use 4 query section to get the result, so the task left is connect these 4 parts, so we need to use array_concat, but it can't support in cosmosdb indeed. At least, I haven't found any function to achieve it until now.

```
SELECT ARRAY_CONCAT((SELECT aa.status,aa.someFlag,aa.score FROM c as aa where aa.status=0 and aa.someFlag=true order by aa.score),
(SELECT bb.status,bb.someFlag,bb.score FROM c as bb where bb.status=1 and bb.someFlag=true order by bb.score)) AS arrayConcat
```

Comment: Yes, I want to get something like this. But I'm afraid it's not possible is cosmosDb just like you said.

Comment: Before someone offer their sql sentence, just trust yourself that it can't be done within one query in cosmosdb. :)

Comment: @Tiny-wa - why are you saying it's impossible? I've done it. And I gave a hint how to  do it, in my comments.

Comment: @Tiny-wa - I think the issue with the OP's question is that there was no sample output shown. Unclear, as written, that it was four completely independent subqueries being combined.

Comment: @Tiny-wa, in case you're interested, it could be done with a simple query and I was overcomplicating it. The working solution: SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.Status = 0 OR c.Status = 1 ORDER BY c.Status DESC, c.SomeFlag DESC, c.Score DESC. It requires composite index with those three fields to work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Husker Congratulations! hh.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my comments, you can combine multiple expressions in your `where` clause, combining them with `or` or `and`.

I think the confusion here is that, in your question, you didn't provide sample output, and it's a bit unclear how you want to perform your sorting. If it's four total queries forming a union, it can be done. If it's four separate queries, where you want each sub-query sorted, then you cannot do such a thing.

For the former: In your example, you can do something like this:

```sql
SELECT c.status, c.someFlag, c.score FROM c
WHERE (c.status = 1 AND c.someFlag = true)
 OR (c.status = 1 AND c.someFlag = false)
 OR (c.status = 0 AND c.someFlag = true)
 OR (c.status = 0 AND c.someFlag = false)
 ORDER BY c.score DESC
```

With input data, including one document that will be filtered out (the one with `status = 2`):

```json
[
    {
        "status": 0,
        "someFlag": true,
        "score": 24
    },
    {
        "status": 0,
        "someFlag": false,
        "score": 25
    },
    {
        "status": 1,
        "someFlag": true,
        "score": 26
    },
    {
        "status": 1,
        "someFlag": false,
        "score": 27
    },
    {
        "status": 2,
        "someFlag": false,
        "score": 0
    }
]
```

Result:

```json
[
    {
        "status": 1,
        "someFlag": false,
        "score": 27
    },
    {
        "status": 1,
        "someFlag": true,
        "score": 26
    },
    {
        "status": 0,
        "someFlag": false,
        "score": 25
    },
    {
        "status": 0,
        "someFlag": true,
        "score": 24
    }
]
```

Comment: You're solution will sort all these results by score and that's not how I wanted it. But nevertheless, you were right, it could be done without some extra work, I was overcomplicating it. Working solution: SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.Status = 0 OR c.Status = 1 ORDER BY c.Status DESC, c.SomeFlag DESC, c.Score DESC. It required composite index with those three fields to work. Thanks for your help.